# Finding the Position of an object without index

Tags: python, list, position

I was wondering is there a method to find the position of an item in a list, in python, without using index? I've tried count and length functions but I'm not sure if my indentation is right or if if I'm writing it incorrectly.

Comment: From your description, in principle it looks like something like `for index, item in enumerate(list): if item == desiredOutcome: return index` would do the work. Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: It looks like you want `list.index()`